# eclipse custom project plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have already read many articles but never succeeded to do what I need.

I would like to make a plugin for eclipse.
this plugin should add new wizard category to the 'File->New->Project',
this category should have 3 items under it, lets say 'X', 'Y', 'Z'.

when pressing each of them, no matter which,
a new 'Create a Java Project' window open.

after entering the 'name' for the project,
a new Folder needs to be create at the project manager at the same chosen 'name'.
this folder must have all other items inside, just like creating a new normal java project.

also should be a new package under the 'src' folder, package name is 'X' ('Y', or 'Z')..
and inside the package should be a java file (with my own default template), its name should be 'name'.jave.

is it possible to make such plugin to eclipse?
even not making the plugin with eclipse itself.

will really appreciate your answer,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You will have to learn how to make Eclipse plugins though. Start with some basic tutorial like [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/firstplugin.htm) or [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html). Then when you know the basics, you can look into the `newWizard` [extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_newWizards.html) that you want to use.

You can do this in any editor, even a text editor if you want. But you will have a huge advantage by doing this in Eclipse since there are editors and tools to help you out.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_newWizards.html

Comment: thank you for the answer. is it possible to make plugin forms using javaFX and FXML files?